# JavaScript para valores monetários?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho essa função para valores monetários:

```
function formatMonetary(v){   
    v = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{15})$/,"$1.$2");
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{11})$/,"$1.$2");
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{8})$/,"$1.$2");
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{5})$/,"$1.$2");
    v = v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1,$2");
    return v;   
}
```

Quando eu uso o número 1 ou 1,1 ela me retorna:

```
0,01
0,11
```

Eu queria que ela me retornasse o número dessa forma:

```
1,00
1,10
```

Ou seja queria que ela me retornasse o número completando os decimais à esquerda, isso é possível?

Comment: Edson, marquei como duplicada de uma outra pergunta que tem imensa informação sobre o que procuras. Diz se mesmo assim não encontrares resposta.

Comment: E se você mudar a direção de digitação do campo no css: [`direction: rtl`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)? É um tiro no escuro, um chute mesmo...

Comment: Alguns sites têm essa mascara, como o do Bradesco e Santander, se você digita 20 ele entende que é 20,00, se você digitar 201 ele entende que é 20,10, não consegui reproduzir